# Get the ViewLayer of a Mesh

Tags: python

If you wished to cull meshes/lights/cameras for export, based on the value of `exclude` value of the view layer of the collection that the object was in, how would you find the view layer?

While the names of the collection & view layer are the same, this much more complicated due view layers being able to be inside of view layers.

The tree of view layers starts at
`bpy.context.window.view_layer.layer_collection` for the `master collection`, the top level view layers are in `.children`, but each of those can also have `.children`.

Kind of seems like I would just need to resort to checking `.visible_get()` on the object.  Was already using that to indicate in the export whether the object should be visible on import though.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know that a mesh can have more than one item for `users_collection`.  Assuming not then this works.

```py
def shouldBeCulled(self, object):
    collectionName = object.users_collection[0].name
    return self.collectionExcluded(bpy.context.window.view_layer.layer_collection, collectionName)
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
def collectionExcluded(self, viewLayer, collectionName):
    print('looking for ' + collectionName + ' in ' + viewLayer.name)
    if collectionName == viewLayer.name: 
        return viewLayer.exclude

    for childViewLayers in viewLayer.children:
        result = self.collectionExcluded(childViewLayers, collectionName)
        if result is not None:
            print('result for ' + collectionName + ' is ' + str(result))
            return result

    return None
```